# jQuery load function links wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am creating am trying to create an interface for an e-commerce website as a personal project.Being a beginer in web development it seems I have stumbled in a problem that I don't understand.I am using jQuery's load function to change the content of 2 divs on click.This is my code's HTML:

```
<ul id="title">
                <li><h2 class="title"><a href="" class="selected">Configureaza</a></h2></li>
                <li><h2 class="title"><a href="">Personalizeaza</a></h2></li>
                <li><h2 class="title"><a href="">Adonuri</a></h2></li>
                <li><h2 class="title"><a href="">Verifica</a></h2></li>
</ul>
<div id="tot">
        <div id="configureaza">
              <div id="stuff">
                    <img src="img/windows.jpg"/>
                           <div id="select">
                                <h2>Selecteaza Produsul Microsoft</h2>
                                <form>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="Windows Vista"/>Windows Vista<span>+320 lei</span></li>
                                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="Windows 7"/>Windows 7<span>+440 lei</span></li>
                                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="Microsoft Office"/>Microsoft Office<span>+220 lei</span></li>       
                                    </ul>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul id="links">
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/msvista_on.gif" title="Sistem de Operare"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/placadebaza.png" title="Placa de Baza"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/procesor.png" title="Procesor"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/aw_optical_on.gif" title="Unitate Optica"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/hd.jpg" title="Hard-Disk"/></a></li> 
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/vs4.jpg" title="Rami"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><img src="img/vc.jpg" title="Placa Video"/></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('img[title="Sistem de Operare"]').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('div#stuff').load('win.html');


            })
            $('img[title="Placa de Baza"]').click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                $('div#stuff').load('motherboard.html');

            })

            $("ul#title a").click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                var link = $(this).text();
                if(link === "Configureaza"){

                    $('div#tot').load('Configureaza.html');

                }else if(link === "Personalizeaza"){

                     $('div#tot').load('Personalizeaza.html');

                }else if(link === "Adonuri"){

                    $('div#tot').load('Addons.html');

                }else{

                     $('div#tot').load('Verifica.html');

                }
                $('ul#title a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');     

            })

        })
```

I have only posted the code for the first 2 links from ul#links because the other code is similar.Ok when I first load the page and I click for example $('img[title="Sistem de Operare"]') the load function works normaly and it loads the elements specified there.But if I click on any of the links in div#tot and then com back on the main page the other links dont work anymore and I noticed an # beinng aded on the link.How can I solve this?

Another problem that I don't understand is that when I try going to the folder where I have the page and open it manualy non of the links will work from the begining.But if I open them from netbeans for example they all work.What am I doing Wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click() is run once when your page first loads up. Once you add new elements with load() even though the selector you used with click() matches these new elements, that selector is not run again and the click() function is not run on them.

In old versions of jQuery we used to use something called "live()" for this, but now the preferred method is to use "on()". So this:

```
$("ul#title a").click(function(e){
```

Should become:

```
$(document).on("click", "ul#title a", function(e){
```

This says, when the document is clicked if the target of the event matches the "ul#title a" selector, go ahead and run the click handler. Since the document is around from the beginning and since the handler is on the document, it doesn't matter when "ul#title a" elements are added to the page, they will always work.